# retrieve data in different format

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Two forms submissions on the same page. two form and fields with diffent ID and names.
One of the two form is working well but I have problem with the second one
I need to get my errors messages normally if wrong entry and if every thing is ok I need array data cause I want to code a message on form step two

**My php code :**

```
//To get errors messages normally
if(!empty($errors2)) {
            $data != "noPassed";
    echo display_errors2($errors2);

}
else {
    //To retrieve data I need to code my message in step 2
        $data2 = array();   
        $data2['client_id'] = $client_id;
        $data2['client_civilite'] = $client_civilite;
        $data2['client_name'] = $client_name;
        $data2['res2'] = "passed";


        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data2);
}
```

**Script :**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url : '/myfolder/parsers/check.php',
        method : 'POST',
        type    : 'POST',
        data : data,
        success : function(data){
        //I presume errors in followed condition
        if (data != 'passed') {
        jQuery('.messages_erreurs').html(data);
        }
        if(data2.res2 == 'passed') {
        $(".frm").hide("fast");
        $("#step2").show("slow");
        $(".open1").css("display","none");
        $(".open2").css("display","inline-block");

       // accès à data.client_civilite, data.client_id, pour message d'identification .

       $('#clt_id').val(data2.client_id);
       $("#check_ok").html(data2.client_civilite+" "+data2.client_nom+" "+': identification réussie.');

      }
```

function to get error messages :

```
function display_errors2($errors2) {
$display2 = '<ul class="bg-danger">';
foreach ($errors2 as $error2){
    $display2 .= '<li class="text-danger">'.$error2.'</li>';
}    
    $display2 .= '</ul>';  

return $display2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should decide what to send back from the php script so that you can easily parse it on the javascript side: Text, html or json.

When the request is successful, you send back json but I don't see that header when there is an error so I suspect you are sending back regular text in that case.

When you send back json, you need to make sure it is parsed before you can use it. You can do that by setting the `dataType` property. Then your `data` variable will be an object (based on the php script...) so you can access the values:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url : '/myfolder//parsers/check.php',
    method : 'POST',
    // Set the correct data type
    dataType : 'json',
    data : data,
    success : function(data){
        // Access the correct values
        if (data.res2 != 'passed') {
            // You need to set the errorText property (or similar) in php
            jQuery('.messages_erreurs').html(data.errorText);
        }
        // etc.
```

Comment: Messages errors are based on data... (I add code below). I made a jason echo and res2 just to retrieve threee datas on step 2